# How does strlen() calculate the length of a string not defined in the current function?

Tags: c, string, strlen

From what I understand, in C arrays and pointers to strings do not implicitly contain information regarding the amount of elements in the respective array. This is why `argc` must be passed to `main()` in addition to `argv`. However, on my machine the following code does correctly print the length of the string `"Hello"` which is `5` even though the string is not defined in the same scope as `printf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void p1(char *a)
{
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(a));
}

void p2(char a[])
{
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(a));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *a = "Hello";
    char b[] = "Hello";
    char c[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    char d[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

    p1(a);
    p2(a);

    printf("\n");

    p1(b);
    p2(b);

    printf("\n");

    p1(c);
    p2(c);

    printf("\n");

    p1(d);
    p2(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are my results and machine type:

> $ ./a.out
> 5
> 5
>
> 5
> 5
>
> 5
> 5
>
> 6
> 6
>
> $ uname -a
>  Linux loathe 3.16.0-37-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 5
>   13:45:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and

> $ cat /etc/issue
>  Ubuntu 14.10 \n \l

How is `strlen()` determining the string length? Why does this work even when the string is explicitly sent as a pointer, as in the function call function `p1(a)`? If this behaviour is only in newer versions of `gcc` and `clang`, when did it start and can I rely on it in my programs?

---

EDIT:

Additionally, why does `strlen()` report an additional character when the null byte is not including in the string? (added in edit)

Edit: I've addressed the assertion that `strlen()` works by finding a null byte.

Comment: Strings in C are 0-terminated: they end with the '\0' char.

Comment: argv is not a string: it's an array of strings (an array of pointers to chars, in fact); the array requires argc, not the individual argv elements. See the type decl: `char *argv[]`.

Comment: "... only in newer versions of gcc and clang? ..." null-terminated strings are older than C itself, finding out counting how long they are goes _way back_.

Comment: I have demonstrated that strlen() is not looking for null bytes, see string `c`. Thank you.

Comment: If you refer to **char array** `d` (not `c`), you have demonstrated just nothing, as _undefined behaviour_ cannot prove anything.

Comment: And `strlen` returns `size_t`, not `unsigned long`. So use the correct format specifier (`"%zu"`).

Comment: @Olaf: Regarding `%zu` in place of `%lu`, the clang compiler specifically mentioned `%lu`. Thank you.

Comment: You are right! It is not "**null**" terminated, as that name is not defined in C and has no meaning at all. However, it is ASCII-`NUL`-terminated, which is the name for `'\0'`.

Comment: Stick with `%lu` for portable code, see my comment to your picked answer

Comment: @FelixPalmen: That is definitively **not** portable. `size_t` can very well be 64 bits, while `long` is 32 bits. That is a very dangerous recommendation - at best.

Comment: @Olaf, no, it's not dangerous. As I wrote over there, you can always take the precaution of converting to long before printing, although there is to my knowledge no existing implementation that has a `size_t` larger than `long`(and it's a recommendation in the standard...). It's very common to always hint about things if they require newer versions of the C standard, and that's probably mostly due to MSVC.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: If you refer to [7.19p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p4), you should read the last sentence. If I have some time, I will check the ARMv8-ABI if that allows for 64 bit size_t. For the standard: If we do not refer to it, there is no sense at all to discuss, as then everything is possible. So, unless one states he does use some non-standard compiler, we should assume at least C99 - for reasons I already listed. Note that even gcc now defaults to C11. And I think they have much more backgrund that you or me.

Comment: @Olaf the point is just that a newer standard doesn't invalidate the older one, it just replaces it. There are still implementations that stick with the older one (on a side note, if someone could convince MS to *move forward* -- no objections). Still, going for maximum portability would mean to stick with the lowest common denominator ... and that is C89. To account for `size_t` being bigger than `long`, you could always use a converting cast. At least for a string length, this should be safe for any sane string.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I bet, there are still K&R compilers in the field. So what would be the acceptable standard? K&R? - no way for me! And C99 changed some semantics compared to C90, so there is also a problem ehere those are involved. If you want to stick with that, just as MS dictates, welcome. I - for myself - will not. Even MISRA has noticed there is a more recent standard and moved on.

Comment: Let me make a single point here: C89/C90 IS a (formal) standard, K&R isn't. That said, I think it's perfectly fine to suggest "better" ways of doing something in newer versions of *standard* C, just note it requires a compiler supporting this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *How is strlen() determining the string length?*

`strlen()` searches for the terminating `null` (`'\0'`), and counts the characters (i.e., number of bytes), from the beginning (pointer), till the `null`, excluding the `null` itself.

***Remember, `C`-style strings are by definition null-terminated.***

Just as a note, as the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`, `%zu` format specifier should be used to print the return value.

---

EDIT:

If a `char` array is not null-terminated, that is **not** qualified to be called as a *string*. Using that kind of array in any *string* related library function will most certainly invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For more info, check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) for `strlen()`.

Comment: I have demonstrated that strlen() is not looking for null bytes, see string c. Thank you.

Comment: @dotancohen what do you mean? My edit got conflicted with yours, so can you please confirm it is in correct state now?

Comment: No you haven't. You mean d. Chances are your variables are aligned so that padding bytes are left after d. And they are probably 0 initially. So your code just prints the "correct" length by accident. d is by definition not a C string (missing the terminating `\0`) -- calling `strlen()` on it is undefined behavior and could crash or anything else.

Comment: and BTW, in this case, `d`  is essentially _not qualified_ to be called a _string_. You're running on  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @SouravGhosh -- about the `z` length modifier: It's GNU specific, so for portable code, better use `l` (and, to be safe in the very improbable case an implementation uses `unsigned long long` for `size_t`, first convert it to `unsigned long`)

Comment: @FelixPalmen No, not at all. It is part of `C11` standard. See §7.21.6.1

Comment: Well, then `C11` adopted it. GNU has it for a long time. No matter what, one widely used compiler just supports `C89` with SOME extensions from `C99` ... you know what I'm talking about :) Suggesting `z` length modifier without any hint about it's availability isn't a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: @FelixPalmen No, it was a part of `C99` also. See §7.19.6.1. If any compiler does not support `C99`, instead of changing the code, I'll humbly recommend to change the compiler itself. It's been a good long 15 years now....

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Current - and only valid - C standard is C11. However, one might accept C99, too, because C11 is "just" 4 years old and mostly adds extensions, but not (much) change C99 features (which C99 did compared to C90; I intentionally ignore the few features made optional). But C90 should _definitvely_ not be considered a valid basis for discussion; even less the mentioned Visual-C compiler (why not mention its name for the unaware?), as that does (obviously) not set the standard.

Comment: The minimal common standard is C89 and it's quite common -- also around here -- to make it explicit when talking about newer features. And also, this whole discussion is pointless now.

Answer (score 4):

Just read the standard. It clearly defines what `strlen` [does](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.3p3). It is **your** assertion which is wrong.

Your **char array** `d` invokes [*undefined behaviour*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.1p1) (last sentence) when used with the string functions.

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally, why does strlen() report an additional character when the null byte is not including in the string? (added in edit)

To answer your edit explicitely: Your assumption is wrong. It could return `42`, crash or even delete your files. Read about Undefined Behavior, as suggested by previous comments.

The technical reason for it reporting 6 is, by accident, in your final program, there is a 0 byte 2 bytes behind your array. That doesn't make the array a valid C string.

Comment: @dotancohen Quite often, this behaviour of accidental zero's (0, `'\0'` or other types of zero's) disappears when you compile with full optimisation on. Try compiling with e.g. the `-O2` or `-Os` option, and see if the results are still the same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your functions `p1` and `p2` are exactly identical.  It is **not** the case that one of them is treating the string as a pointer, and the other one is treating the string as an array.  A string is, by definition, an array of characters.  *But*, whenever we manipulate arrays (and, in particular, when we pass an array to a function) what we're actually using is a pointer to the array's first element.  So your function `p2`, even though it looks like it's receiving an array, is actually receiving a pointer.  See also [this question](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Now, secondly, a C string *does* contain, explicitly, an indication of its length: all proper strings contain a null terminator, the special character `'\0'`, which marks its end.  How you determine a string's length is to read through it, counting characters, until you find the `'\0'`.  That's exactly what `strlen` does.

Finally, we come to your array `d`.  As I think you know, you have arranged that this array look sort of like the string `"Hello"`, but *without* the terminating null character.  So when `strlen` tries to compute the length of `d`, it's going to sail right past the end, and start inspecting whatever random area of memory exist past the end of the array.  There are three things that might happen:

- The next thing in memory right after the array might just happen to be a 0 byte.  In this case, by pure chance, `strlen` will just happen to compute the correct answer, 5.
- It's more likely that there are some other random bytes in memory following the array, and that somewhere within them is a 0 byte.  In that case, `strrlen` will compute an answer greater -- perhaps much greater -- than 5.  That's what appears to have happened.
- Before finding a 0 byte, `strlen` might run past the end of the memory allocated to your process, in which case you will get some operating-system-level error message, such as a Segmentation violation or Bus error or "This program has terminated unexpectedly" or Blue Screen Of Death.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of `strlen`

```
size_t strlen(const char * str) {
    const char * s;
    for (s = str; *s; ++s);
    return(s - str);
}
```

The loop termination condition `*s` is internally `*s != '\0'`. So, it loops until terminating `null` character is found. And, it behaves the same for both a `pointer to char` and a `char array`.